# Using NPM package with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to use [html-differ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-differ) npm package in one of my ASP.NET MVC project with
which does not have node. I googled but did not find any js lib of html-differ which I can use without node. Is there is any way we can create js lib for npm packages?

Comment: yes you can. there are some bundlers available like browserify which allows you to bundle all the imported package to a single js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment:

You must bundle your JavaScript application with a bundler.
Personnaly, I use webpack or fuse-box (simpler, lighter, faster), then use your JS bundle in your ASP.NET application!

Hopes this helped!